# Consuming RESTful API with Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, rest, api, xamarin.forms

New to Xamarin.forms.

The following code should generate a list of games and bind it to a list view, but it does not. I am using the Refit library. The URL in Postman returns the JSON list as intended. Where should I start?

ISteamService.CS

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Refit;

namespace PatchNotes
{

[Headers("Content-Type: application/json")]
public interface ISteamService
{
    [Get("/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=XXXXC&include_appinfo=1&steamid=XXXX")]
    Task<string> GetGames();
}

}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Refit;

namespace PatchNotes
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void OnGetGamesClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var apiResponse = RestService.For<ISteamService>("https://api.steampowered.com");
        var games = await apiResponse.GetGames();

        GamesList.ItemsSource = games;

    }
}
}
```

MainPage.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="PatchNotes.MainPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="40">
         <Button Text="Get Games" Clicked="OnGetGamesClicked" 
BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" 
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

          <ListView x:Name="GamesList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
           </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: for trouble-shooting issues between the web api and xamrin forms app, firstly make the web api work. You can test your web api with tools like Postman ( https://www.getpostman.com/ ). No need to use  xamarin forms app at this stage. Once web api is working, you can debug your mobile app in visual studio and see what's wrong.

Comment: GetGames returns a single string value, but a ListView ItemsSource must be an IEnumerable (ie, an array/list/collection).  I'm guessing GetGames returns a json array, if so you need to tell Refit to deserialize it to the proper type

Answer (score 1):

According to [this documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29) `GetOwnedGames` will return a JSON (as Jason guessed correctly) with the following structure

```
{
    "game_count": <number of games>,
    "games": [ 
        {
            "appid": "...",
            "name": "...",
            "playtime_2weeks": ,
            "playtime_forever": ,
            "img_icon_url": "",
            "img_logo_url": "",
            "has_community_visible_stats": "" 
        }, ...]
}
```

You cannot simply assign this string to `ItemsSource` and expect *Xamarin.Forms* to figure out for you, you will have to take care how this is deserialized.

You will have to write a class that is used to deserialize your JSON string. *Refit* will do the deserialization, but you need a class to deserialize to anyway:

```
public class GamesList
{
    [JsonProperty("game_count")]
    public int GameCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("games")]
    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    [JsonProperty("appid")]
    public string AppId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("playtime_2weeks")]
    public int PlayedMinutesInTheLastTwoWeeks { get; set; }

    // And so on. Depending on what you need.
}
```

(See the [JSON.Net documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonPropertyAttribute) on `JsonProperty`)

You can now redefine your `ISteamService`

```
[Headers("Content-Type: application/json")]
public interface ISteamService
{
    [Get("/IPlayerService/GetOwnedGames/v1/?key=XXXXC&include_appinfo=1&steamid=XXXX")]
    Task<GamesList> GetGames();
}
```

and use it from your `OnGetGamesCicked` like

```
var apiResponse = RestService.For<ISteamService>("https://api.steampowered.com");
var gamesList = await apiResponse.GetGames();

GamesList.ItemsSource = gamesList.Games;
```